# What command-line to use in Symfony2 framework in windows

Tags: symfony

I'm creating a website using Symfony2 framework but I can't get proceed to the creation of the website because I don't know where to type like these

`$ php symfony configure:database "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jobeet" root mYsEcret`,

`$ php symfony doctrine:build-schema`.

It seems an Linux command and it doesn't work on windows command-prompt.

What commandLine should I used for this ?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add your PHP installation directory to the `%PATH%` environment variable, or work from the PHP installation directory.

To add it to path (The best approach - *Edited for Windows 7*):

- Right-click on a `My Computer` icon
- Click `Properties`
- Click `Advanced system settings` from the left nav
- Click `Advanced` tab
- Click `Environment Variables` button
- In the `System Variables` section, select `Path` (case-insensitive) and click `Edit` button
- Add a semi-colon (`;`) to the end of the string, then add the full file system path of your PHP installation (e.g. `C:\Program Files\PHP`)
- Keep clicking `OK` etc until all dialog boxes have disappeared
- Close your command prompt and open it again
- Sorted

Alternatively, you can run `cd <PHP installation path>` before you try and run you command, or call your script like `<FULL file system path of php.exe> <path to script>`

Then you open the CMD and you write the Symfony commands

Comment: What do you mean by PHP? I didn't installed php, I'm only using XAMPP and Sublime for code editing.

Comment: You go into this path : `c:\xampp\php\` this is the directory that contain the php.exe

Comment: Conclusion : you replace `C:\Program Files\PHP` by `C:\xampp\php`

Comment: When I type this `php symfony configure:database "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jobeet" root mYsEcret` in CMD, it say `could not open input file: symfony`. what is the error with this?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use Easyphp, it has phpreg.exe (or something like that) that will put php in %PATH% variable. It also allows you to create virtual hosts from browser, and easyphp will take care of everything else.

Instead of Sublime, use Phpstorm. It has by far the **best** Symfony2 plugin of all editors. If you are still learning S2, you will definatelly need autocompletion for forms, services, doctrine... Just amazing!

Comment: Thank you @Zeljko for your advice. But what I'm trying to do now is modifying the OrangeHRM (open source web app I found in sourceforge) that uses Symfony :)